# amchart with load plugin PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, amcharts

In script I have the code below:

```
<script>
var pie_chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartpie",{
  "type"    : "pie",
  "depth3D": 15,
  "theme": "light",
    "titleField"  : "category",
  "valueField"  : "column-1",
  "angle":30,
  "minRadius" : 50,
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "dataLoader": {
    "url": "loadPie.php",
    "format": "json"
    }
});
</script>
```

In `loadPie.php`, I have the code below:

```
<?php
        // Set proper HTTP response headers
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        $link  = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'pharmana_general', '123456pharmana', 'pharmana_Hareket_db');
         mysqli_set_charset($link , "utf8"); /* Procedural approach */
        $query = "  SELECT SUM(KDV) AS TotalKDV,Ana_Kategori
                    FROM general_Table
                    GROUP BY Ana_Kategori";
        $result = $link->query( $query );
        // Print out rows
        $data = array();
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
          $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

This should work but it doesn't, it only shows white space. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

(I included this code in html:

```
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the fields from the data being returned by your PHP script matches the `titleField` and `valueField` in your chart for the DataLoader plugin to work with your pie chart. Your PHP script seems to be returning an array of rows with `TotalKDV` and `Ana_Kategori`, but your `valueField` and `titleField` are set to `"column-1"` and `"category"`, respectively. Assuming your data looks like this:

```
[{
  "Ana_Kategory": "Category 1",
  "TotalKDV": 10
},{
  "Ana_Kategory": "Category 2",
  "TotalKDV": 20
}]
```

Your `valueField` needs to be `"TotalKDV"` and `titleField` needs to be `"Ana_Kategori"`:

```
var pie_chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartpie",{
  "type"    : "pie",
  "depth3D": 15,
  "theme": "light",
  "titleField"  : "Ana_Kategori",
  "valueField"  : "TotalKDV",
  "angle":30,
  "minRadius" : 50,
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "dataLoader": {
    "url": "loadPie.php",
    "format": "json"
    }
});
```